# The SetApprovalForAll is not working when I try to transferFrom from a marketplace

Tags: solidity, nft, remix

I built a NFT smart contract called AliveNatureERC721 and I also built a marketplace contract called `AliveNatureMarketplaceV1`.

Both contracts are below. I'm using Remix. I got an error

> Fail with error 'Only the owner of NFT can transfer or burn it'

on the `ERCNFT.transferFrom( msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId)` even when I went to the deployed NFT smart contract on Remix and executed the function `setApprovalForAll("marketplace smart contract address", true)` before I called the function `listNFT(ERC721 _nft, uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price, address _coin)`.

I also tried to call the `setApprovalForAll` function inside the marketplace smart contract and didn't work either.

Here is the call I'm doing:

```
Marketplace address: 0x3f46f42900DDFE85FC03B80D934608a8C2522Dc
NFT address: 0x2CF055487A80014a10d75D4EC86de2b0Ac1C9B0e

setApprovalForAll("0x3f46f42900DDFE85FC03B80D934608a8C2522Dc", true)
```

after I call `ERCNFT.transferFrom( msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId);` where `address(this)` is `0x3f46f42900DDFE85FC03B80D934608a8C2522Dc`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in this case.

Marketplace smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";


contract AliveNatureMarketplaceV1 is Ownable, Pausable,  ReentrancyGuard  {
    IERC20 public ERC20;
    IERC721 public ERCNFT;

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    
    Counters.Counter private numOfListing;

    uint256  commissionPercentage = 250;

struct NFTListing {  
  ERC721 nft;
  uint tokenId;
  uint price;
  address coin;
  address seller;
  bool forSale;
}
  
  event NftBuy(address _buyer, uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price);
  event NftList(address _seller, IERC721 _nft, uint256 _tokenId);
 
  mapping(uint256 => NFTListing) public listings;
   
   modifier onlyNftOwner(uint _Id) {
        require(msg.sender == listings[_Id].seller);
        _;
    }


    function pauseMarketplace() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpauseMarketplace() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

  
// this function will list and sell an NFT into the marketplace
  function listNFT(ERC721 _nft, uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price, address _coin) public  {
    ERCNFT = IERC721(_nft);
    require (ERCNFT.ownerOf(_tokenId) == msg.sender, "You are not the owner");
    require(_price > 0, "NFTMarket: price must be greater than 0");
    numOfListing.increment();
    listings[numOfListing.current()] = NFTListing(
       _nft,
       _tokenId,
       _price,
       _coin,
       payable(msg.sender), 
       false
       );
    NFTListing storage listing = listings[_tokenId];
   //ERCNFT.approve(address(this) , _tokenId);
  // listing.nft.setApprovalForAll(ERCNFT, true);
    ERCNFT.transferFrom( msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId);
    listing.forSale = true;
     emit NftList(msg.sender, ERCNFT, _tokenId);

  } 



// this function will cancel the listing. it also has checks to make sure only the owner of the listing can cancel the listing from the market place

  function cancel(uint _Id) public payable onlyNftOwner(_Id){
     NFTListing storage listing = listings[_Id];
     require(listing.seller == msg.sender);
     require(listing.forSale == true);
     listing.nft.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _Id);
     listing.forSale = false;
  }



// this function will facilitate the purchasing of a listing
  function buyNFT(uint _Id) public payable whenNotPaused nonReentrant {
        NFTListing storage listing = listings[_Id];
        require(_Id > 0 && _Id <= numOfListing.current(), "item doesn't exist");
        require(msg.value >= listing.price,"not enough balance for this transaction");
        require(listing.forSale != false, "item is not for sell");
        require(listing.seller != msg.sender, "You cannot buy your own nft");

        uint256 comissionAmount = SafeMath.mul(listing.price, commissionPercentage);
        comissionAmount = SafeMath.div(comissionAmount, 10000);
        uint256 sellerAmount = SafeMath.sub(listing.price, comissionAmount);


        if (listing.coin == 0xF194afDf50B03e69Bd7D057c1Aa9e10c9954E4C9){
        require(sellerAmount <= address(this).balance, "Insufficient funds.");
        payable(address(this)).transfer(comissionAmount);
        payable(listing.seller).transfer(sellerAmount);
        } else {
          ERC20 = IERC20(listing.coin);
          require(sellerAmount <= ERC20.balanceOf(address(this)), "Insufficient funds.");
          ERC20.transfer(address(this), comissionAmount);
          ERC20.transfer(listing.seller, sellerAmount);

        }
        listing.nft.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, listing.tokenId);
        listing.seller = msg.sender;
        listing.forSale = false;
        emit NftBuy( msg.sender, listing.tokenId, sellerAmount);
    }

     // Function to transfer or withdraw the funds
    function transferOrWithdraw (bool _isCelo, uint _amount, address _ERC20Address) public whenNotPaused nonReentrant onlyOwner {
        require(_amount != 0, "Amount cannot be zero");
       if (_isCelo) {
            require(_amount <= address(this).balance, "Insufficient funds.");
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(_amount);
        } else {
            require(_ERC20Address != address(0), "ERC20 address cannot be zero address");
            ERC20 = IERC20(_ERC20Address);
            require(_amount <= ERC20.balanceOf(address(this)), "Insufficient funds.");
            ERC20.transfer(msg.sender , _amount);
        }
    }

// this function will get the listings in the market place
    function getNFTListing(uint _Id) public view returns (NFTListing memory) {
        return listings[_Id];
    }

    
    // get list of items
    function getListinglength() public view returns (uint) {
        return numOfListing.current();
    }   


  

}
```

NFT SMART CONTRACT

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/common/ERC2981.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";


contract AliveNatureERC721 is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage,Ownable ,ERC2981,  Pausable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;


    //Base URI
    string private url;
    // percentage split for commission 
    uint96 public commissionPercentage;
    // address of the commission recipient
    address public commissionRecipient;

    struct ProjectData {
        string name;
        uint256 projectTokenId;
        string methodology;
        string area;
        string region;
        string emissionType;
        string uri;
        address creator;
        uint256 timeStamp;
    }

    struct RetireData {
        uint256 retireTokenId;
        address beneficiary;
        string retirementMessage;
        uint256 timeStamp;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    mapping (uint256 => ProjectData) private _projectData;
    mapping (uint256 => RetireData) private _retireData;




    constructor( string memory _MyToken, string memory _Symbol) ERC721(_MyToken, _Symbol) {
        commissionPercentage = 100;
        commissionRecipient = 0xE3506A38C80D8bA1ef219ADF55E31E18FB88EbF4;
        _setDefaultRoyalty(commissionRecipient, commissionPercentage);
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view override returns (string memory) {
        return url;
    }

    function pause() external onlyOwner  {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() external onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }


    function safeMint(address _to, string memory _uri, string memory _name,
    string memory _methodology, string memory _area, string memory _region,  string memory _emissionType, uint256 _tokenId) public whenNotPaused onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenId;
        _safeMint(_to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, _uri);
        
        // Create a new ProjectData struct and store it in the contract's storage
        _projectData[tokenId] = ProjectData({
        projectTokenId : tokenId,
        uri : _uri,
        name : _name,
        methodology : _methodology,
        area : _area,
        region : _region,
        emissionType : _emissionType,
        creator : msg.sender,
        timeStamp : block.timestamp
        });
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, uint256 batchSize)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId, batchSize);
            if (from != address(0)) {
            address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
            require(owner == msg.sender, "Only the owner of NFT can transfer or burn it");
        }
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal whenNotPaused override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function burnToken(uint256 tokenId, string memory _retirementMessage, uint256 _amount) public whenNotPaused {
        address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Only the owner of NFT can burn it");
        _burn(tokenId);

        // Create a new ProjectData struct and store it in the contract's storage
        _retireData[tokenId] = RetireData({
        retireTokenId : tokenId,
        beneficiary : msg.sender,
        retirementMessage : _retirementMessage,
        timeStamp : block.timestamp,
        amount : _amount
        });
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC2981,  ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }



    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override(ERC721, IERC721) returns (address) {
        address owner = _ownerOf(tokenId);
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: invalid token ID");
        return owner;
    }

    function getProjectData(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (ProjectData memory) {
        return _projectData[tokenId];
    }

    function getRetireData(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (RetireData memory) {
        return _retireData[tokenId];
    }

    function getCommissionPercentage() public view returns (uint96) {
        return commissionPercentage;
    }

    function getCommissionRecipient() public view returns (address) {
        return commissionRecipient;
    }

}
```

I tried to follow many examples that call that I need to first executa setApprovalforAll but even that still don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require(owner == msg.sender, "Only the owner of NFT can transfer or burn it")`

The error tells it all, the `owner` is not the `msg.sender`.

When calling `ERCNFT.transferFrom`, the `msg.sender` will be the address of **the Marketplace contract**. Your logic inside `_beforeTokenTransfer` restricts every address except the token owner to do the transfer, even if that address got approved.

Comment: the problem is you modify the `_beforeTokenTransfer` function, breaking the approval logic